# Would do that or would have done it?

Tags: would, have

Is there a situation in which following sentence is correct?

> "You could have mentioned you would do that"

If so, then in which context is it right? I mean, if the sentence is started by "could have" then the next part should contain "have" after "would" in this case? Is this a rule or does it all depend on the situation in which you're using it? And if so, please present me the right context.

Comment: They're both correct, but can have different meanings. "You paid for everyone's meals. You could have mentioned you would do that – I'd have been able to come if I'd known you'd be paying." // "So you really would have let him go if he'd asked you? You could have mentioned you would have done that." (although the other variant works here too).

Comment: @Edwin: Usually, *you **would have** done that* implies ***if** some hypothetical situation had arisen in the past, **but in fact it didn't*** (so by further implication, you ***didn't*** do it). But there can be "habitual past action" contexts where it means you definitely ***did*** do it (*repeatedly!* :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's allowed.  We're looking back, to look forwards again.

Consider a situation where one housemate leaves some drugs lying around.  The second housemate finds them and flushes them down the toilet.

> Housemate A:  Err did you see that little bag I left by the phone?
>
> B: What, the drugs?  Yes, I flushed them down the loo.
>
> A: WHAT??!  Why?
>
> B: I don't want any drugs in my house.  My sister's kids come round
>   here all the time.  So, if I see any drugs I will just flush them.
>   *A: You could have mentioned you would do that*.
>
> B: The subject never came up before.

Answer (score 1):

The tenses already match in my opinion.
One of the meanings for 'would' is:

> used as the past form of will when reporting what somebody has said or
>   thought 
>   *He said he would be here at eight o'clock* (= His words were: ‘I will be there at eight o'clock.’).
>   *She asked if I would help.* 
>   *They told me that they probably wouldn't come.*   Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 9th edition © Oxford University Press, 2015